# PageSpeed Insightsで表示されるスピードの単位について

Tags: untagged

速度改善などで、「改善すると〇〇 s早くなります」と書いてありますが、この『s』という単位は秒を表しているのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

単位がわからず困っています。

Comment: 普通は`"ms"`と記載がない限り`"s"`と来たら`sec`だと思いますが、そう思った理由がありますか？

Comment: Siegさん
=>secだと思ったのですが、スピードを見たページを開くのにかかった時間そんなにかかってないなぁと思ってしまい、あってるのか不安になってしまいました。

Answer (score 1):

ドキュメントをなめて見たのですが、下記のようにあったので秒だと思います。

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about
`presented in seconds and milliseconds respectfully.`
(それぞれ秒とミリ秒で表示します。)

また、画像に注釈する形で`between 1,000ms and 2,500ms.`とあり、
画像中で`2.3 s`となっていますので、ミリ秒の時は`ms`と表記されると思います。